# How to best handle datetime in lists or in Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, list, time

I am trying to compare a list of datetime or dataFrame but it gives me a few errors like th

AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'between_time' or 'loc'

```
Example Data: 
observed_time = ['2020-02-20T15:54:00Z', '2020-02-20T16:54:00Z']

slice_begin_time=['2020-02-20T17:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T18:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T19:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T20:50:00Z', '2020-02-20T21:50:00Z']
slice_end_time=['2020-02-20T18:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T19:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T20:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T21:05:00Z', '2020-02-20T22:05:00Z']

### LIBS
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd

df=pd.to_datetime(check_time)
for i in range(len(slice_begin_time)):
    sdf = df.between_time(pd.Timestamp(slice_begin_time[i]),pd.Timestamp(slice_begin_time[i]))
    print(sdf)
```

I tried

```
 #print(check_time.loc[(check_time > pd.to_datetime(slice_begin_time[i])) & (check_time < pd.to_datetime(slice_end_time[i]))])
```

To find out what was wrong but then it gives me

> AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'loc'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is variable `df` is assigned to `DatetimeIndex`, also [`DataFrame.between_time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) working with times, not datetimes:

```
df=pd.to_datetime(observed_time)
```

You can `zip` both lists and use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(observed_time))
for start, end in zip(slice_begin_time, slice_end_time):
    sdf = s[s.between(pd.Timestamp(start),pd.Timestamp(end))]
    print(sdf)
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
s = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime(observed_time))
for i in range(len(slice_begin_time)):
    sdf = s[s.between(pd.Timestamp(slice_begin_time[i]),pd.Timestamp(slice_end_time[i]))]
    print(sdf)
```